# Setting up Django with Gunicorn and Nginx on Synology NAS 1818+ (DSM 6.2): nginx syntax test failed due to Permission denied issue

Tags: nginx, deployment, synology

I am attempting to deploy a Django application on my Synology NAS 1812+, which is running DSM 6.2. My setup involves using Gunicorn and Nginx. Unfortunately, I'm encountering a persistent issue related to file permissions when trying to configure Nginx.
The nginx configuration  file is saved in the folder "/etc/nginx/sites-availables/".
Then the server block configuration is symlinked in the "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/" using:
`sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/DjangoTest /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

Issue:
When I run sudo nginx -t, to load the configuration into nginx, I receive the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/DjangoTest" failed (13: Permission denied) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:366
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Steps Taken:

1. Checked the file permissions for '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/DjangoTest' and they seem correct (lrwxrwxrwx).
2. Tried giving read permissions to everyone for the DjangoTest file using `sudo chmod a+r`. I also tried `sudo chmod 755`and `sudo chmod 777`. But it always yield the same error with permission denied while running `sudo nginx -t`.
3. Adjusted ownership of the DjangoTest file to the nginx user and group (also tried with http group based on the NAS user-group configuration).
4. Verified the nginx.conf file to ensure it's including files from the sites-enabled directory correctly.
5. Ensured the content of DjangoTest configuration is syntactically correct.

Additional Information:

1. My NAS model is 1812+, and I'm running DSM 6.2. Upgrading to DSM 7.2 isn't an option for me. (I know that DSM7.2 can natively run python written project, but DSM7.2 is not available for my NAS)
2. I have set up Gunicorn to serve the Django app, and it works fine locally.
3. I have confirmed that the ports are open and the DDNS service is functioning correctly.

As sudo is not granting me the permission to perform the nginx configuration file syntax checking test, can anyone guide me on how to resolve this permission issue or provide insight into other potential problems in my setup?